# Cannot pass super keyword as an argument to method in java

Tags: java

Why below program does not work fine?
instead of super in below code if we give this keyword as an argument it will work fine, what is the difference between two codes.
Thanks in advance

```
class Vehicle
{
  int maxSpeed = 120;
}

/* subclass Car extending vehicle */
class Car extends Vehicle
{
  int maxSpeed = 180;

  void display()
{
  test(super);
  /* print maxSpeed of base class (vehicle) */
  // System.out.println("Maximum Speed: " + super.maxSpeed); 
}
  public void test(Vehicle obj)
{
  System.out.println("Maximum Speed: " + obj.maxSpeed);
}
}

/* Driver program to test */
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Car small = new Car();
    small.display();
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `super` would be the same as `this`, i.e. you're passing the *real* object (which could be a subclass of `Car`), so the Java language forces you to use `this` for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

There is a misconception on your end. *this* refences to a real object, therefore you can pass it to any method that allows for an instance of the corresponding class.

But there is no separate *super* object! *super* is nothing but a helper mechanism that allows you to access methods or fields of the super class (and it only works *within* a derived class). It is not intended to deliver a real object refence!

And note: that also doesn't make sense conceptually. You can't really separate the super class properties when looking at a child class due to polymorphism.

It is really simple: you pass *this*, nothing else. If your code doesn't work then, then that would be a symptom of a bug in your design!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Your method `test` receives a instance of a `Car`, and keyword `super` it's used to call parent methods, *through* child class. `this` keyword returns the instance of the class.

What you're trying to achieve is call `super()` constructor to pass a instance of a Car to the method, but java states that the the `super()` call can be used only once in the constructor class as the first statement, to ensure that class will inherit from it's parent, or Object class directly. If you not states it, Java implicitly does it for you.